# Javascript regex to create nested html list item

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to achieve the same functionality that is available on StackOverflow to convert below format into `ul` and `li`.

Sample input:

```
- a
 - b
 - c
- d
```

Expected output:

```
<ul>
   <li>
       a
       <ul>
          <li>b</li>
          <li>c</li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li>d</li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible with JavaScript regex?

What I have tried?

```
function convertToList(text) {
    return text.replace(/((?:^(- ).*$\r?\n*)*^(- ).*$)/gm, function($0, $1) {
        return '<ul>' + $1.replace(/^(- )(.*)$/gm, '<li>$2</li>') + '</ul>';
    });
}
```

but it doesn't work for nested list items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to accurately recreate the functionality from this site, then I would look at using a [markdown library](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js).

Making parsers with Regex can be [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: I found one more mark down library [showdown-highlight](http://softwaremaniacs.org/playground/showdown-highlight/) that can make my life easier.